# Enable OpenSSL on MAMP MYSQL (MAC)

Tags: mysql, macos, ssl, openssl, mamp

Hi i'm having a problem trying to enable SSL on Mysql (MAMP version 3.0.5 for mac) 
When i try to add :

```
ssl
or ssl-ca=/Users/myuser/Documents/ssl/ca-cert.pem
```

lines on my.cnf 
On the log of mysql i got the **Error**

```
unknown variable ssl
unknown variable ssl-ca=
```

can someone help me please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if mysql was compiled with ssl support using `mysqld --ssl --help`. You will get `unknown option --ssl` if its not compiled in.

You can also try the following queries `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'have_ssl';` and `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'have_openssl';`

If you don't have it compiled in you may need to replace it with the version from homebrew/macports or compile from source.

Comment: Thank you this helped me verry much :-)